# Multiple Time Series in one Auto_arima code

Tags: arima, model-selection

I hope you can help me with the following. I am using the `Auto_ARIMA` function (`pmdarima` library) to calculate my p, d and q values. For example, to calculate my p, d, q for "Product 1" I would run

```
auto_arima(df['Product 1'], seasonal =True, m=12).summary()
```

Is there a way I can "add" Product 2 and 3 to the same line of code? I tried the following, but it doesnt work

```
auto_arima(df['Product 1' , 'Product 2', 'Product 3'], seasonal=True, m=12).summary()
```

Any suggestions? My goal is to forecast the sales for multiple products.

[image: Sales for Product 1, 2 and 3]

Comment: See [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77285/), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/) and [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383312/).